# (jsx) Use padEnd in an element's text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, padding, jsx

```
const text = 'testing'.padEnd(25) + 'John'

return (
    <li>{text}</li>
)
```

expected result:

```
<li>testing                  John</li>
```

Actual output:

```
<li>testing John</li>
```

What is the simplest way to get the expected result?

Related to this: [Best practice when adding whitespace in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40264084/10238810)
But how should I go about it with padding?

Comment: Try `.padEnd(25, '&nbsp;')`.

Comment: @FrankerZ That didn't work: output: `<li>testing &nbsp;&nbsp;John</li>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HTML tag [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre), that maintains the text as presented, to surround the `text` variable.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const text = 'testing'.padEnd(25) + 'John';
    return (
      <div><pre>{text}</pre></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```