# How to add spaces between different tags

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tags

I have some code that looks like this

```
<div class="topnav">
  <div>{{getGameView.Game.gameplayers[0].player.username}}</div>
  <p>VS</p>
  <div v-if="getGameView.Game.gameplayers.length > 1">
　  {{getGameView.Game.gameplayers[1].player.username}}
　</div>
  <div v-else>Waiting for opponent...</div>
</div>
```

Which prints this: NameVSName
I am trying to make it so that between Name and VS there is some space but cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: use &nbsp; in your html where you want the space

Comment: Or even better go for styling in css and refer that class on p tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to give to the `VS` element a class like `.vs` and add some `padding` to it:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  display: flex;
}

.topnav .vs {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div>Name</div>
  <p class="vs">VS</p>
  <div>Name</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a space in html with `&nbsp;`.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nameA: "Job",
    nameB: "Bob"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ nameA }}&nbsp;Vs&nbsp;{{ nameB }}
</div>
```

[How to insert spaces/tabs in text using HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792849/how-to-insert-spaces-tabs-in-text-using-html-css)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, adding `{{}}` solved that.

```js
<div class="topnav">
  <div>{{getGameView.Game.gameplayers[0].player.username}}</div>
  {{}}
  <p>VS</p>
  {{}}
  <div>
    {{
      getGameView.Game.gameplayers.length > 1
        ? getGameView.Game.gameplayers[1].player.username
        : 'Waiting for opponent...'
    }}
  </div>
</div>
```

As an aside, in React it is `{' '}`.
*ref:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/47001733