# What is {" "} in React JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What is meant by `{" "}` in React JSX? I see it in the code below:

```jsx
 <p><a href="/" className="mx-1">Home</a> {" "}| {" "} <a className="mx-1" href="/about-us">About 
 Us</a> {" "}|{" "}<a className="mx-1" href="/terms">Terms</a></p>
```

Comment: `{` `}` is how you interpolate JavaScript expressions into JSX. `{" "}` is just interpolating a space character.

Comment: Yes but it's not needed to interpolate a simple space is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is used to interpolate JavaScript inside your JSX.

Using `{' '}`is used to insert a space inside your JSX while avoiding any side effet. Using this to insert a space does not insert any HTML tag in your code.

See: [Best practice when adding whitespace in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264084/best-practice-when-adding-whitespace-in-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the ways of adding additional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add JavaScript inside your JSX, you need to use `{}`

To add a space `{' '}` can be used. But generally, the prettier converts some spaces in the editor into `{' '}`.