# Prettier or VSCode formatting with unwanted behavior. Adding {' '}

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, prettier

I have a problem with prettier. The code would format in an unwanted way.

How can I solve this problem?

I have checked prettier docs and tried going through the settings config.
After formatting is applied to **Figure A** there is unwanted formatting behavior in which {' '} curly braces with single quotation of space inside is added. See **Figure B**

```html
<h1 className='title'>
     Read <Link href="/posts/first-post"><a>this page!</a></Link>
</h1>
```

[image: Figure A]

```html
Read{' '}
   <Link href='/posts/first-post'>
     <a>this page!</a>
   </Link>
```

---

[image: Figure B]

Comment: Can you mention what type of file (lang/framework) are you working on

Answer (score 1):

That's how whitespace works in JSX. See this question: [Best practice when adding whitespace in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264084)

If Prettier split the line without adding that space in braces, the output of your code would change: `Readt̲h̲i̲s̲` instead of `Read t̲h̲i̲s̲`.