# How to prevent collapseWhitespace in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I have run into issue related to [How to avoid JSX component from condensing when React.js rendering it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686728/how-to-avoid-jsx-component-from-condensing-when-react-js-rendering-it) . I would like to find a way how to avoid using `{' '}`. I have red somewhere that changing `collapseWhitespace` to `false` in webpack could resolve it. Is it achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Inside JSX create-react-app will not collapse any white space, so

```
<p>Hello   World - Hello{'   '}World</p>
```

will result in:

```
<p>Hello   World - Hello   World</p>
```

However, the browser will usually collapse these white spaces into a single one. To prevent this set the 'white-space' css property like this:

```
<p style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre' }}>Hello   World - Hello{'   '}World</p>
```

The collapseWhitespace property exists for HTML minification as part of the html-webpack-plugin. This property is true for CRA and will minify the contents of `public/index.html`. In order to disable it you would have to [eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject).

See: [cra-webpack-config](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/1cbc6f7db62f78747cb6ca41450099181139325e/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L587)

Comment: Im my case I am talking about white spaces between inline-block elements

`<input type="radio" />{'  '} <label>Some label</label>`

As some CSS frameworks rely on inline block spacing. More info on issue: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/.

Would setting `collapseWhitespace` to `false` keep the white spaces between inline-block elements? I do not want to get rig of this spaces but leave them.

Comment: I have tried to `eject` and change `collapseWhitespace` to `false` it still removes whitespaces between inline-block elements.

Comment: collapseWhitespace will not have an effect on the React JSX part. As described in the answer, the spaces from JSX will not be collapsed. So when I tried your example I've had two spaces in between input and label. The issue might be related to the CSS framework you're using.